# Multilingual Reports

Tags: report, multilingual

Is there any reporting tool which offers multilingual support (namely English en-US and Arabic ar-KW) and support for Web report viewing in IE6 and above. I don't want to end up making different reports for each added language. Development platform for this is ASP.NET 3.5, Crystal Reports or any compatible reporting tool, SQL Server 2000/2005, IIS 6/7.

One way I figured out works if we are only working with the static data then we can add and replace the translations of static text (labels, headers etc) using reports formulas. I'm not sure whether it works with older reports versions but I've tested and it did worked with CR 9 and above. But this is off no use when we need to change the positioning and ordering of the reports columns as well for right-to-left and left-to-right layout languages like English and Arabic...

What is the recommended and best known/developed way to deal with this?

Any bright idea and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try http://www.stimulsoft.com/

This has all you can dream of and even more !!!!

I mean it !

(It has localization inbuild in the reports so you don't have to make multiple reports etc,just change cultures etc if you know .net culture classes etc)

(There is a version that works on web)

Comment: The site doesn't say anything about multilingual support??? Have you tested this?

Comment: Visit the forums and search for localization or globalization.Or download install and check GlobalizedReport sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/)** (used to be i-net Crystal-Clear). It support translations of your reports with resource bundles. It support also mirroring of Arabic reports.

Answer (score 0):

Our [ActiveReports Product](http://www.datadynamics.com/ActiveReports) supports multiple languages in the scenario you describe. Being the number one selling report writer [in Japan](http://www.grapecity.com/tools/products/activereportsnet6) for many years now has also allowed us make big investments in international support for complex languages like Japanese and Chinese that others tend not to such as special handling for exporting Japanese or Chinese characters (and other languages) to PDF.

```
Scott Willeke
GrapeCity
```

Answer (score 0):

[Izenda AdHoc Reports](http://www.izenda.com/Site/Pages/languagepack.aspx)
provides wide opportunities for multilingual support.
You could change static text(labels etc.) as well as testxs from the database on-the-fly. Really on-the-fly, i.e. change language in one click.

[Izenda AdHoc](http://www.izenda.com) supports right-to-left languages "from the box" and also there is Arabic language pack already. If you need another dialect you could contact support and they will tell you how to get it.
And another great thing is you can easily change any translation you'd like by just editing simple XML file.